# checked and unchecked checkbox dynamically using angular

Tags: angular, html, checkbox

I want to make the checkbox checked and unchecked from the function  based on value , if suppose checkbox value is 120, how to make that checkbox checked

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked] = "isEnabled" value={{rowData.FILE_LOAD_ID}} id={{rowData.FILE_LOAD_ID}}>
```

Comment: Can you add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I already have isEnabled variable that sets value based on different condition onInit, later i want to check and uncheck the checkbox based on checkbox value

Comment: $('input.type_checkbox[value="6"]').prop('checked', true); I need this condition in typescript. please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `[checked] = "rowData.FILE_LOAD_ID==120"`

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked] = "rowData.FILE_LOAD_ID==120" value={{rowData.FILE_LOAD_ID}} id={{rowData.FILE_LOAD_ID}}>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[checked] = "isEnabled()"
```

add function

```
isEnabled() {  
return this.someValue === 120; 
}
```